# ggsave using svg device throwing "bad value" error following update of package

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg, ggsave

I am adding another example of: **Don't update packages when working with a perfectly fine running script!**

I am struggling to find the solution for an error which is thrown by ggplot's ggsave function after updating several packages yesterday.

Prior to the update, everything worked fine, but afterwards the same script (no changes made) threw the following error:

```
> ggplot2::ggsave(
+   filename = params$file_plot_output,
+   plot = p1
+ )
Error in match_font_c(family, as.logical(italic), as.logical(bold)) : 
  bad value

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.0

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.5.0 RSQLite_2.3.1 readxl_1.4.3  dplyr_1.1.3  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.5         gtable_0.3.4      compiler_4.3.1    crayon_1.5.2     
 [5] tidyselect_1.2.0  blob_1.2.4        tidyr_1.3.0       textshaping_0.3.7
 [9] systemfonts_1.0.5 scales_1.2.1      yaml_2.3.7        fastmap_1.1.1    
[13] ggplot2_3.4.4     R6_2.5.1          generics_0.1.3    tibble_3.2.1     
[17] munsell_0.5.0     svglite_2.1.2     DBI_1.1.3         pillar_1.9.0     
[21] rlang_1.1.1       utf8_1.2.3        cachem_1.0.8      stringi_1.7.12   
[25] bit64_4.0.5       memoise_2.0.1     cli_3.6.1         withr_2.5.1      
[29] magrittr_2.0.3    grid_4.3.1        rstudioapi_0.15.0 lifecycle_1.0.3  
[33] vctrs_0.6.4       glue_1.6.2        cellranger_1.1.0  ragg_1.2.6       
[37] fansi_1.0.5       colorspace_2.1-0  purrr_1.0.2       tools_4.3.1      
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

I did some troubleshooting with installing/reinstalling brew/fontconfig/cairo. Also installed/reinstalled the extrafont package and the svglite package, but nothing fixed the problem.

I know this is currently not a lot of information to troubleshoot, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I cannot really identify where the problem lies given the error message. I also tried to change the font (`family` argument for `theme` in ggplot2), but this did not help either.

**The problem seems to be specific for svg. I have no problems saving the exact image/plot as PDF, png and so on.**

Alternatively, if someone has a quick way of reinstating my last package setup (basically rolling back the updates I made yesterday), that would be great too.

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()` and `ggsave("mtcars.svg", plot = gg)` work for me (lnx, R-4.3.1, ggplot2-3.4.4). As for rolling back updates, do you know the previous versions? If so, you can use https://packagemanager.posit.co for looking for specific versions.

Comment: I suspect that something in your plotting code is changing the default fonts, font family, or something else. I don't suspect that shiny is doing something to the process, so it might be useful to make a more reproducible example that is not using shiny reactivity. If it's reproducible and identified as a bug, my guess is that the maintainers will not want the bug report to be based on shiny (unless that truly is something needed to reproduce it).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for the comments! Running the example you used on your machine (using the mtcars dataset) actually worked for me too, without throwing the error. Weird however is the fact that my code even works with other file formats such as PDF or PNG as output. The only time the error occurs is with SVG output, which is my preferred output unfortunately.

Comment: With respect to shiny.... I am not running shiny here. The params is just my way of calling variables defined in my external YAML document so... no shiny used here.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I mis-spoke ... I inferred r-markdown from the use of `params$file_plot_output`. Either way, it's hard to dive into this atm. Is there a way to reproduce this with some minimal code?

Comment: Hi @r2evans. I am also not using R-Markdown. I am using the YAML file passing parameters for a normal R script. However, the minimal example works. Also however, it is surprising to me that my error using my code only occurs with SVG as output, a no other file format. Trouble shooting is indeed tricky as the minimal code works, my script however is quite long and removing components to identify what specific code results in the error is tricky. But again: I thought the SVG vs. other file formats hints towards a problem...

Comment: Same bug here...